# How to invalidate cache on Google Cloud Bucket in php code

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cdn

i'm using Google Cloud Bucket as CDN. When i upload an image to CDN, i set `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000` (365 days). Then i want to replace that image by another one, but i don't know how to invalidate the old cache. I'm using Google Cloud PHP Client SDK https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php.

I tried to delete the old image and upload a new image but it didn't work. I still get the old version.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the PHP API client nor the JSON API expose this admin method

... therefore one could only wrap the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content#invalidating_cached_content) command with PHP-CLI:

```
function clear_cdn_cache($urlmap_name) {
    $cmd = 'gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache '.$urlmap_name.' --path "/*"';
    $stdout = shell_exec($cmd); 
    echo "<pre>$stdout</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This solution doesn’t use Google Cloud PHP, however if you check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content#invalidating_cached_content), you may find the answers you are looking for.